# Multiple row insert in SQL Server from Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I need to insert multiple rows into SQL Server database (100 at a time) from my Java code. How can I do this? Currently I am inserting one by one and this does not look efficient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`PreparedStatement#addBatch()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) to create a batch and [`executeBatch()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) to execute it.

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Item item = items.get(i);
        statement.setString(1, item.getSomeValue());
        // ...
        statement.addBatch();
        if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0) {
            statement.executeBatch(); // Execute every 100 items.
        }
    }
    statement.executeBatch();
} finally {
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

**See also**:

- [JDBC tutorial - using PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [JDBC tutorial - batch updates](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html)

Comment: in this approach if one record from the batch fails what will happen..? will the records after the failed record be inserted...how do i make sure that except the record that fails all other records be inserted...?

Comment: That actually depends on the driver used. See [`executeBatch()` javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Use a batch.

Check out the addBatch(), executeBatch(), etc. methods of Java's [Statement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

For a simple example, check [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-execute-a-batch-process-with-jdbc.html) (but I would suggest using a PreparedStatement)

Comment: is there a batch statement in sql server or do i need to use a api...?

Comment: @Kaddy - I would recommend doing it on the Java side with a batch using PreparedStatement

Answer (score 1):

You can pass one very long string to SQL with multiple inserts as one statement to SQL Server.  This won't work if you're doing parameterized queries, though.  And concatenated SQL strings are "Generally a Bad Idea."

You might be better off looking at the [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command.   It has the problem of being rigid about column orders and such.  But its WAY FAST!!

Comment: i cant use this because i dont have a file...thanks anyways...

Comment: yeah, its a PITA to write the file and such, but its a good command to be aware of.  :)